# Flush to Zero when a computation results in a denormal number in linux

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754, underflow

A computation in my C code is producing a gradual underflow, and when it happens the program is terminating with SIGFPE. How can I flush the result to zero when a gradual underflow (Denormal) results from a computation, and not terminate the execution? (I am working on a redhat linux machine). Thanks.

Comment: Did you do anything special to make your program terminated on underflow? I thought that nowadays underflow was mostly handled in microcode which, while slower than the hardware implementation for normalized results, would be completely transparent to the software layers.

Comment: Is there any flag that i can add when I compile in gcc to enable FTZ when a gradual underflow occurs?

Comment: Probably not a gcc flag, but code you can execute, certainly. However the person who will be able to answer your question may be interested in knowing how you got your program to receive SIGFPE on underflow, since this is not the default behavior. It may even be relevant information to help that person help you.

Comment: There is unlikely to be anything magical for your program about denormalized numbers. If they are appearing, you must also have numbers that are very small but normalized. Why are they valid, but the denormalized ones should be zero?

Comment: How do you know gradual underflow is occurring, and what makes you think it is the cause of the SIGFPE? Is your debugger `gdb` and, when the program gets SIGFPE, do the commands `info float` and `print $mxcsr` work? What is their output? What is the output if you execute them at the start of the program? (Use `break main`, then `run`, then `info float` and `print $mxcsr`?) When the SIGFPE occurs, can you execute `x/i $pc` to see the failing instruction, and can you print the contents of the operands of the instruction?

Answer (score 4):

You haven't specified the architecture - I'm going to take a guess that it's a relatively recent x86[-64], in which case you can manipulate the SSE control register using `_mm_getcsr`, `_mm_setcsr`, specified in the `<xmmintrin.h>` (or `<immintrin.h>`) header.

The 'flush-to-zero' bit is set with 0x8000, and 'denormals-are-zero' (for inputs / src) is set with 0x0040.

`_mm_setcsr(_mm_getcsr() | 0x8040);` or with `<pmmintrin.h>` (SSE3) :

`_mm_setcsr(_mm_getcsr() | (_MM_FLUSH_ZERO_ON | _MM_DENORMALS_ZERO_ON));`

This might make it easier to determine the source of the underflow, but it shouldn't be considered a solution, since the FP environment is no longer IEEE-754 compliant.

Comment: GCC/clang `-ffast-math` when linking an executable will link in CRT startup code that does this, setting FTZ and DAZ.